# A questions about HashMap's time Complexity

Tags: hash, linked-list, hashmap, time-complexity

This is not a code questions iam just trying to understand the concept of hashmaps and time complexity.

Well i think i know how hashMaps/sets etc. work and i think i understand why HashMaps.get has a constant time but when we have a very big hashMap the indicies where the values get stored should overlap. When 2 hashcodes resolve to the same index they get stored in a LinkList at this index right?.

Couldn't it be that all elements got stored in one index as a link List. Shouldn't now HashMap.get run at worst case in O(n).

Comment: Yes you're correct. It depends on the implementation of the hash function. One of the main properties of `hash()` is uniformity, every hash value being generated with roughly the same probability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the worst case time complexity for `HashMap` is O(n) where `n` is the number of elements stored in one bucket. The worst case will be when all the `n` elements of the HashMap gets stored in one bucket.

However this can be improved if binary search is implemented for each of the buckets. In that case the worst case time complexity will be `O(log(n))` as `binary search tree` is used to store the elements instead of a `doubly linked list`.